# How do I get contents from a Firestore Array in Unity?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling to make sense of Firestore arrays in Unity/C#.

```
DocumentSnapshot snap = task.Result;
IDictionary<string, object> dict = snap.ToDictionary();
object questData = dict["questData"];
```

How do I say results = dict["questData"][0].results?

[image]

[image]

Debugger shows questData as object I can't figure out how to say:
object[] questData = dict["questData"]

It comes in from Firestore as an object but it's really an array.

Comment: what is is written when you debug in Type (see spy window) for questdata or have you the structure of object..

Comment: what do you have if you type: var x = dict["questData"] as object[]

Answer (score 1):

i dont see if its array or list oe IEnumerable..

but you could use that to unbox object:

```
var x =dict["quesData"] as object[] or List<object>
```

and following the type you apply the same schema.

if collection (ict["questData"]) is dictionary you could apply that:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in dict["questData"])
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

to find the other keys, i dont see if key is string, so object should does the job in case...

so you could write too:   `var x =dict["quesData"] as Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: Thank you Frenchy

Comment: Doesn't work I get error: KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)

Comment: of course the collection is Dictionary so you have to adapt the code following the type of collection..so i know ist nosql database, but you haven't a minimun data struture of data you trap?